# push_back for strings without converting to vector

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++. I can't figure out how to add a `std::string` to the end of a `std::string` without making it a `std::vector`..

Right now I have:

```
string returnvar;
for (int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
    returnvar.push_back(library[data[i]]);
}
```

but `push_back()` is meant to be used with `std::vector<std::string>` not `std::string`.  How would I just push on to the end on the `std::string` like:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
```

and so on with each iteration of the loop

Comment: I guess I am. Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the += operator:

```
string returnvar;
for (int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
    returnvar += library[data[i]];
}
```

or the `append` function (edited to reflect Jerry Coffin's correction):

```
string returnvar;
for (int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
    returnvar.append(1, library[data[i]]);
}
```

More info:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/

Comment: There is no overload of `append` that only takes a single character parameter. As shown in my answer, if you're going to use `append`, you need to use something like: `append(1, library[data[i]]);`

Comment: You need to swap the parameters, and use the `&` operator as well: `returnvar.append(&library[data[i]], 1);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that would work as well. It would use the overload: `basic_string& append(const charT* s, size_type n);`. I was using the overload: `basic_string& append(size_type n, charT c);` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: if you were going to use the overload you mentioned, you might as well get rid of the loop and use: `append(&library[data[start]], end-start);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I thought about that, but the use of `data[i]` as an index into `library[]` to get each character suggests that the characters being appended might not be stored  sequentially in memory.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why what I wrote wouldn't work. We don't know that he is only trying to append one character. He just says he wants to append two `std::string`s. Look at this: https://ideone.com/ZdjrXD The code compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: Actually, it does show one character being appended "a ab abc abcd". But still, it works. I updated the example to show this.

Comment: @JerryCoffin In the example I provided, `returnvar.append(library[data[i]])` seems to work fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the example seems to work fine without the `&` operator.

Comment: @SFBA26: Yes, when using `append(size_type n, charT c)`. I was assuming he meant to use `append(const charT* s, size_type n)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, you were referring to Jerry Coffin's comment. I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to my answer. As a member with an incredibly high reputation, can you explain why my answer has 3 down votes? The answer I gave works and answered the question, right?

Comment: @SFBA26: Probably because your answer contains an error by referring to a non-existent overload of `append()`, which Jerry pointed out to you and you have not corrected yet. Instead, you updated your answer with a different example that passes just a single `string` as input to `append()`, which `append()` has an overload for, whereas the OP is clearly using an array of chars instead (as evident by `std::string::push_back()` only accepting a single `char` as input), which `append()` does not have an overload that accepts just a single `char` as input.

Comment: Ah, okay, I missed that `std::string::push_back()` only accepts a single char. I couldn't figure out why it was assumed he was trying to append a `char`, but that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification, I'll fix the answer. Or would deleting it be more appropriate?

Answer (score 7):

`std::string` has a `push_back()` method, just like `std::vector`'s (§21.4.6.2/21):

```
void push_back(charT c);
    Effects: Equivalent to append(static_cast<size_type>(1), c).
```

You could use `operator+=` instead:

```
returnvar += library[data[i]];
```

Or one of the `append()` overloads:

```
returnvar.append(&library[data[i]], 1);
```

```
returnvar.append(1, library[data[i]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string returnvar;
for (std::size_t i = start; i <= end; ++i)
{
    returnvar += library[data[i]];
}
```